# TypeScript > Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

При создании динамического компонента React на TypeScript выходит Warning, просьба подсказать что делаю не так?

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

```js
interface IProps {
  items: ISelectorProps[];
  width: string;
  changeEvent(e:number):void;
}

export const CustomSeletor: React.FC<IProps> = ({ items, width, changeEvent }) => {
  const mystyles = {
    width: width,
  } as CSSProperties;
  const handleChange = (e:number) => {
      changeEvent(e)
  }
  const options = items.map(({ value, name }) => <Option key={value} value={value}>{name}</Option>);
  return (
    <Select style={mystyles} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[доки](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

---

так работает

```
<CustomSeletor width="150px" items={items} changeEvent={changeEvent} />
```

так - нет

```
<CustomSeletor ref="qq" width="150px" items={items} changeEvent={changeEvent} />
```

---

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactfc-ref-err-6zydv

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

type ISelectorProps = {
  value: any;
  name: any;
};

interface IProps {
  items: ISelectorProps[];
  width: string;
  changeEvent(e: number): void;
}

const Option: React.FC<any> = ({ value, children }) => (
  <option value={value}>{children}</option>
);
const Select: React.FC<any> = ({ style, children }) => (
  <select style={style}>{children}</select>
);

const CustomSeletor: React.FC<IProps> = ({ items, width, changeEvent }) => {
  const mystyles = {
    width: width
  }; // as CSSProperties;
  const handleChange = (e: number) => {
    changeEvent(e);
  };
  const options = items.map(({ value, name }) => (
    <Option key={value} value={value}>
      {name}
    </Option>
  ));
  return (
    <Select style={mystyles} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options}
    </Select>
  );
};

const items: IProps["items"] = Array.from({ length: 3 }, (q, i) => ({
  value: `qqq ${i}`,
  name: `qqq ${i}`
}));
const changeEvent = e => console.log(e);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* is OK */}
      <CustomSeletor width="150px" items={items} changeEvent={changeEvent} />
      {/* is BAD */}
      {/* <CustomSeletor ref="qq" width="150px" items={items} changeEvent={changeEvent} /> */}
    </>
  );
}
```